# :nth-child() not work on li added with foraeach data-bind

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Im making a single page app on codepen.io (http://codepen.io/ntibbs/pen/ZbPPBm?editors=101) using knockout.js and jquery and while trying to figure out a way to select individual `<li>` elements that are added to my page using a foreach binding I noticed I can not use `:nth-child()` to do this. All the elements are considered `:nth-child(1)`, not sure why its doing that. Are there any ways I could select an individual `<li>` element ?

Answer (score 0):

The n in `:nth-child()` represents the depth, not the order. So `:nth-child(1)` selects every element that is the first child of its parent.

I'm not sure under what conditions you're trying to select a particular element, but I'll give you some options.

- If each element already has a unique identifier, use that.
- If you are already iterating through the set of elements, use logic in your loop to get the one you want.

If you can give me some more info on that, I can edit this accordingly.